# R sparse matrix stores zeros after simple arithmetic (Matrix library)

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have the following [10 x 10] sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
m = as(diag(10), 'sparseMatrix')
m
10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
[1,] 1 . . . . . . . . .
[2,] . 1 . . . . . . . .
[3,] . . 1 . . . . . . .
[4,] . . . 1 . . . . . .
[5,] . . . . 1 . . . . .
[6,] . . . . . 1 . . . .
[7,] . . . . . . 1 . . .
[8,] . . . . . . . 1 . .
[9,] . . . . . . . . 1 .
[10,] . . . . . . . . . 1
```

If I do simple arithmetic on this, it now stores all of the zeros.

```
M = m + 1 - 1
M
10 x 10 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
```

I know that I can make this new matrix sparse, but is there any way to make R do this automatically?

```
M = as(M, 'sparseMatrix')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calculates `m+1-1` as `(m+1)-1` and `m+1` is not sparse so from that point on you don't have a sparse matrix.

Try `m+(1-1)`.

Comment: I know this is what's happening, but I was surprised that there was no workaround. Thanks.